# Creating text files from array, using FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I created an array of strings and placed them into an array called schoolsArray. I want to be able to create a text file for each school, using fs.

For some reason, I just can't get this to work. It seems that the issue is with using the value from schoolsArray[0] as a string in the path name. Please take a look at my series of tests. This first code snippet all works, but I added it just to help you understand that I import 'fs' and create a directory first.

**Update - Added schoolArray creation per request**

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Read all schools into array (read from text file)
const schoolFile  = "./assets/dispatch/state/schools/county_name.txt";
fileInput         = fs.readFileSync(schoolFile, "utf-8");
const schoolArray = fileInput.split("\n");

// Variable for chat logs directory
const chatDir = "./chat-logs";

// Create directory if it doesn't exist
if(!fs.existsSync(chatDir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(chatDir);
}
```

The directory is created, now try make a file attempt #1

```
var schoolTextFile = chatDir + "/" + schoolArray[0] + ".txt";
fs.writeFileSync(schoolTextFile, "");

Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Node_Webkit_Test\chat-logs\Test School Name.txt'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:653:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1300:33)
```

Okay, so that doesn't work for some reason. Attempt #2 - I have come to think that the schoolArray[0] value isn't being read as a string, so I tried this:

```
var schoolTextFile = chatDir + "/" + toString(schoolArray[0]) + ".txt";
fs.writeFileSync(schoolTextFile, "");
```

There are no errors here, but the output is an undefined object:

[image]

Attempt #3 was to simply try a text string instead of using the value from my array. This worked exactly as intended.

```
var schoolTextFile = chatDir + "/" + "some Text 1234" + ".txt";
fs.writeFileSync(schoolTextFile, "");
```

[image]

Thus, the issue is pinpointed to be with the schoolArray[0] value being entered into the path. It seems silly to even test, but I did this anyway...

```
var somestring = "some text 1234";

console.log(typeof somestring);
// The log says that this is a string.
console.log(typeof schoolArray[0]);
// The log says that this is a string.
```

So then, why does one string work here, and the other causes path issues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is not clear where schoolArray comes from and what it contains

Comment: Where / How is your `schoolArray` defined? Where is it in relation to your `writeFileSync()` call, i.e. is it imported, if so was it properly imported?

Comment: I will add the schoolArray to the code, one moment.

Comment: what console.log(schoolArray) prints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have some forbidden characters in schoolArray. Typically `\r`. Try

```
schoolArray = fileInput.split("\n").map( line => line.replace(/\r/g,''));
```

Comment: That worked! However,could you please explain what the '/g' is for? I understand the rest. Thanks!

Comment: g is for a global search (see RegExp doc). In other words, it replaces **all** occurrences of \r. You may not need it here, since you expect only one \r at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks! I write mostly in C/C++/Java, and have never used global once in my regEx's, very cool!